# How to interact with table on webpage with Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, html

I'm trying to make a program for work to automate a spreadsheet that we maintain. The information is on a third party website that we log in to and then scroll through a bunch of pages and then a table is there with all of the info in it. I used selenium webdriver to open internet explorer, log you in, then navigate you to the correct page but I don't know how to interact with the table. When I inspect element in Gooogle chrome, there is no ID or name showing up for the table or any of its cells. Thanks in advance guys.

Edit:
Here is the HTML Code. I put asterisks for sensitive info. The asterisked info is what I need to pull. I only posted the first quarter or so of the code because it's too many characters but the code just repeats for more rows.

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>***************</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">                                                        
function to_SchedForm(theForm) {                                                 
var j = 0;                                                                         
if (theForm.p_chkbox_cnt.value == 1)
{
        if (theForm.p_part_chkbox.checked ){                                             
            ++j;                                                                    
        }                                                                         
}
else{
for (var i = 0; i < theForm.p_part_chkbox.length; i++ ) {                             
        if (theForm.p_part_chkbox[i].checked ){                                             
            ++j;                                                                    
        }                                                                         
}                                                                                 
}
if (j == 0) {                                                                     
    alert("No Part Numbers Selected");                                             
    return false;                                                                      
}                                                                                  
return true;                                                                     
}                                                                                  
function to_MultiSchedForm(theForm) {                                             
var j = 0;                                                                         
var c = 0;                                                                     
var k = 0;                                                                     
for (var i = 0; i < theForm.p_part_chkbox.length; i++ ) {                             
     if (theForm.p_part_chkbox[i].checked ){++k;
         if (theForm.p_mode_chk[i].value != "CR"){                                      
            ++j;                                                                    
         }                                                                         
       }                                                                               
}                                                                                  
if (k == 0) {                                                                     
    alert("No Part Numbers Selected")
    return false;                                                                       
}                                                                                  
if (j != 0 && theForm.ACTION1.value == "multi_order") {                                                                     
    alert("The Multiple Schedule Update option is only available for Schedules that currently have a blank Last Commit value.  Use the Individual Schedules Button to change a commitment Date.")
    return false;                                                                       
}                                                                                  
return true;                                                                     
}                                                                                  
</SCRIPT>                                                                            
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<TABLE  BORDER="0" WIDTH="100%"
                  CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0">
<TR>
<TD WIDTH="100%", VALIGN="top"><IMG SRC="/apps/space/img/PPPS_NEW.jpg" ALT="GM Banner" NAME="PPPS1"></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD width="50%"><HR></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE  BORDER="0" WIDTH="100%" CELLSPACING="0"
                   CELLPADDING="0">
<TR>
<TD WIDTH="100%", VALIGN="top", ALIGN="center"><IMG SRC="/apps/space/img/priority3.jpg" ALT="Priority Banner" NAME="Priority1"></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<BR>
<CENTER>
<TABLE  WIDTH="100%">
<TR>
<FORM ACTION="Schedule.PrioritySummary" METHOD="POST" NAME="to1_PS_Page">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_PERSON_ID" VALUE="BZRGJH">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_mode" VALUE="EDIT">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_type" VALUE="SCHEDULE">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_space_duns" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_onum" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_proc" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_zcode" VALUE="BL62">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_one" VALUE="part_number">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_two" VALUE="priority">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_three" VALUE="commit_mode">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_four" VALUE="po_rel_sort">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_supplier" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_zcodes_space" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_duns" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_part" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_sort_type" VALUE="none">
<TD VALIGN="BOTTOM" ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B> Part #:</B><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="p_pnum" SIZE="12" MAXLENGTH="12"></FONT><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="GO"></TD>
</FORM>
<FORM ACTION="Schedule.PrioritySummary" METHOD="POST" NAME="to2_PS_Page">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_PERSON_ID" VALUE="BZRGJH">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_mode" VALUE="EDIT">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_type" VALUE="SCHEDULE">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_space_duns" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_pnum" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_proc" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_zcode" VALUE="BL62">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_one" VALUE="po_rel_sort">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_two" VALUE="part_number">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_three" VALUE="priority">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_four" VALUE="commit_mode">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_sort_type" VALUE="none">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_supplier" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_zcodes_space" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_duns" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_part" VALUE="">
<TD VALIGN="BOTTOM" ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B> Order #: </B><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="p_onum" SIZE="12" MAXLENGTH="12"></FONT><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="GO"></TD>
</FORM>
<FORM ACTION="Schedule.PrioritySummary" METHOD="POST"  NAME="to3_PS_Page">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_PERSON_ID" VALUE="BZRGJH">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_mode" VALUE="EDIT">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_type" VALUE="SCHEDULE">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_space_duns" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_pnum" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_onum" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_zcode" VALUE="BL62">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_one" VALUE="po_rel_sort">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_two" VALUE="part_number">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_three" VALUE="priority">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_four" VALUE="commit_mode">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_sort_type" VALUE="none">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_supplier" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_zcodes_space" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_duns" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_part" VALUE="">
<TD VALIGN="BOTTOM" ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B><SELECT NAME="p_proc"><OPTION VALUE="0">&lt; Select Processor &gt;<OPTION VALUE="KXH">K.Hr 918040497243         <OPTION VALUE="SJF">S. Fox 586-484-0855       </SELECT></B></FONT><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="GO"></TD>
</FORM>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</CENTER>
<HR>
<CENTER>
<FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2">Mfg. DUNS: <B>178522926</B></FONT>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>KAUTEX INC</B></FONT>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2">Z-code: <B>BL62</B></FONT>
</CENTER>
<CENTER>
<TABLE  WIDTH="100%" BORDER="2" BORDERCOLOR="#00008B">
<TR>
<TH VALIGN="CENTER" ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="5%" BGCOLOR="darkblue"><CENTER><FONT COLOR="WHITE" SIZE="-1"><B><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2">Select One or More</FONT></B></FONT></CENTER></TH><FORM ACTION="Schedule.PrioritySummary" METHOD="POST"  NAME="to4_PS_Page">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_PERSON_ID" VALUE="BZRGJH">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="iv_group" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_mode" VALUE="EDIT">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_type" VALUE="SCHEDULE">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_space_duns" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_duns_number" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_zcode" VALUE="BL62">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_pnum" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_onum" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_proc" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_sort_type" VALUE="part_num">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_one" VALUE="part_number">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_two" VALUE="priority">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_three" VALUE="commit_mode">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_four" VALUE="po_rel_sort">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_supplier" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_zcodes_space" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_duns" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_part" VALUE="">
<TH  BGCOLOR="darkblue"><CENTER><FONT COLOR="WHITE" SIZE="-1"><B><INPUT TYPE="image" NAME="p_img" SRC="/apps/space/img/Part_Number_Button2.gif" border="0"></B></FONT></CENTER></TH></FORM>
<TH VALIGN="CENTER" ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="21%" BGCOLOR="darkblue"><CENTER><FONT COLOR="WHITE" SIZE="-1"><B><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2">Description</FONT></B></FONT></CENTER></TH><FORM ACTION="Schedule.PrioritySummary" METHOD="POST"  NAME="to5_PS_Page">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_PERSON_ID" VALUE="BZRGJH">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="iv_group" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_mode" VALUE="EDIT">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_type" VALUE="SCHEDULE">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_space_duns" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_duns_number" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_zcode" VALUE="BL62">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_pnum" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_onum" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_proc" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_sort_type" VALUE="ordr_num">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_one" VALUE="po_rel_sort">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_two" VALUE="part_number">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_three" VALUE="priority">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="c_sort_four" VALUE="commit_mode">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_supplier" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_zcodes_space" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_duns" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_part" VALUE="">
<TH  BGCOLOR="darkblue"><CENTER><FONT COLOR="WHITE" SIZE="-1"><B><INPUT TYPE="image" NAME="p_img" SRC="/apps/space/img/Order_Number_Button2.gif" border="0"></B></FONT></CENTER></TH></FORM>
<TH VALIGN="CENTER" ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="7%" BGCOLOR="darkblue"><CENTER><FONT COLOR="WHITE" SIZE="-1"><B><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2">Last Commit</FONT></B></FONT></CENTER></TH><FORM ACTION="Schedule.PrioritySummary" METHOD="POST"  NAME="to6_PS_Page">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_PERSON_ID" VALUE="BZRGJH">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="iv_group" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_mode" VALUE="EDIT">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_type" VALUE="SCHEDULE">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_space_duns" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_duns_number" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_zcode" VALUE="BL62">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_pnum" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_onum" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_proc" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_sort_type" VALUE="none">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_supplier" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_zcodes_space" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_duns" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_part" VALUE="">
<TH  BGCOLOR="darkblue"><CENTER><FONT COLOR="WHITE" SIZE="-1"><B><INPUT TYPE="image" NAME="p_img" SRC="/apps/space/img/Due_Now_Button2.gif" border="0"></B></FONT></CENTER></TH></FORM>
<TH VALIGN="CENTER" ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="5%" BGCOLOR="darkblue"><CENTER><FONT COLOR="WHITE" SIZE="-1"><B><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2">Due 11/03</FONT></B></FONT></CENTER></TH><TH VALIGN="CENTER" ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="5%" BGCOLOR="darkblue"><CENTER><FONT COLOR="WHITE" SIZE="-1"><B><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2">Due 11/10</FONT></B></FONT></CENTER></TH><TH VALIGN="CENTER" ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="5%" BGCOLOR="darkblue"><CENTER><FONT COLOR="WHITE" SIZE="-1"><B><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2">Due 11/17</FONT></B></FONT></CENTER></TH><TH VALIGN="CENTER" ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="5%" BGCOLOR="darkblue"><CENTER><FONT COLOR="WHITE" SIZE="-1"><B><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2">Due 11/24</FONT></B></FONT></CENTER></TH><TH VALIGN="CENTER" ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="5%" BGCOLOR="darkblue"><CENTER><FONT COLOR="WHITE" SIZE="-1"><B><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2">Future</FONT></B></FONT></CENTER></TH><TH VALIGN="CENTER" ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="5%" BGCOLOR="darkblue"><CENTER><FONT COLOR="WHITE" SIZE="-1"><B><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2">Total</FONT></B></FONT></CENTER></TH><TH VALIGN="CENTER" ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="5%" BGCOLOR="darkblue"><CENTER><FONT COLOR="WHITE" SIZE="-1"><B><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2">SNR</FONT></B></FONT></CENTER></TH></TR>
<FORM ACTION="Schedule.SchedForm" METHOD="POST" NAME="toSchedForm"onSubmit="if (this.ACTION1.value == 'single_order')
                                    {
                                       if (to_SchedForm(this))
                                       {
                                           return true
                                       }
                                       else
                                       {
                                          return false
                                       }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                       if (to_MultiSchedForm(this))
                                       {
                                          document.toSchedForm.action=&quot;Schedule.multi_schedform&quot;;return true
                                       }
                                       else
                                       {
                                          return false
                                    }
                                       return false
                                 }">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_EMS_DIVISION" VALUE="M ">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_DOC_PREFIX" VALUE="XQ">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_DOC_NUMBER" VALUE="APHL ">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_DOCUMENT_TYPE" VALUE="Q">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_PART_DLS" VALUE="A">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_PART_PLS" VALUE=" ">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_PART_NUM" VALUE="23214821">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_mode_chk" VALUE="CR">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_chkbox_cnt" VALUE="1">
<TR>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER" ALIGN="CENTER"><B><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="p_part_chkbox" VALUE="1"></B></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT FACE="CourierNew" SIZE="2"><B>******** </B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2">TANK ASM - FUEL                                       </FONT></TD>
<TD><FONT FACE="CourierNew" SIZE="2">*******</FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                     ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>-</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                            ALIGN="CENTER"><B><FONT COLOR="*****" FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"></B><B>12</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                            ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>0</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>0</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>0</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>0</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>0</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>****</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>-</B></FONT></TD>
</TR>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_EMS_DIVISION" VALUE="M ">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_DOC_PREFIX" VALUE="XQ">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_DOC_NUMBER" VALUE="APHL ">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_DOCUMENT_TYPE" VALUE="Q">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_PART_DLS" VALUE="A">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_PART_PLS" VALUE=" ">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="P_PART_NUM" VALUE="***********">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_mode_chk" VALUE="CR">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_chkbox_cnt" VALUE="2">
<TR>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER" ALIGN="CENTER"><B><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="p_part_chkbox" VALUE="2"></B></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="RIGHT"><FONT FACE="CourierNew" SIZE="2"><B>******** </B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2">TANK ASM - FUEL                                       </FONT></TD>
<TD><FONT FACE="CourierNew" SIZE="2">J1UJ3  -000</FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                     ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>-</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                            ALIGN="CENTER"><B><FONT COLOR="FF0000" FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"></B><B>*****</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                            ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>0</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>0</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>0</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>0</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>0</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>********</B></FONT></TD>
<TD VALIGN="CENTER"
                                         ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT FACE="courierNew" SIZE="2"><B>-</B></FONT></TD>
```

Comment: can you paste the HTML code for the tables

Comment: just edited it in. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so its useful to know that you can find any element by its element id, e.g. `driver.findElement(By.id("table"))`. This will give you the first element of that type. However, you have multiple tables, so you'll need to find a way to get the right table.

There are different ways to do this, but they'll usually revolve around some individual characteristic of your target. In this case the obvious example for me is that it contains this:

```
<TR>
<TD WIDTH="100%", VALIGN="top", ALIGN="center"><IMG SRC="/apps/space/img/priority3.jpg" ALT="Priority Banner" NAME="Priority1"></TD>
</TR>
```

Though this means we're looking down into children levels (makes things a little more complicated). What we can do is look for that particular element and then find its parent table via xpath like in [this xpath tutorial](http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/xpath-tutorial-for-selenium).

1. So, to find the image element we simply use:

`WebElement imageElement = driver.findElement(By.name("Priority1"));`

This gives us the image element.

2. To find the table containing said `imageElement` we then use:

`WebElement tableElement = imageElement.findElement(By.xpath(//ancestor::table));`

This should find the ancestor element that is a table containing the priority1 image.

I suggest you have a look at how x-path works. Its very useful, but sometimes it does require a little tinkering (especially if a web page changes).